# Java UnknownFormatConversionException when printing double value using printf

Tags: java, oop, interface

When I compile this code I get warnings and the compiler asks to recompile it with -Xlint. When I recompile it with -Xlint and I run the code I get java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException. Please help me identify my mistake and how can I rectify it. Thanks in advance.

> ***I have enclosed some of my other doubts in the comments line in the code itself.***
>   One more thing where can I get good material for studying Collections in Java in depth.

```
import java.util.*;
public class ComparableTest{
public static void main(String args[]){
TreeSet studentset=new TreeSet();
studentset.add(new Student("mike","hauffmann",101,4.0));
studentset.add(new Student("john","lynn",102,2.8));
studentset.add(new Student("jim","maxx",103,3.6));
studentset.add(new Student("kelly","grant",104,2.3));
Object studentarray[]=studentset.toArray();//this line needs explanation. Why are we creating an array of Object class? Is there any other alternative to this program without referring to Object class?
Student s;
for(Object obj:studentarray){
    s=(Student)obj;
    System.out.printf("NAME = %s %s STUDENT ID = %d GPA = %.lf", s.firstName(), s.lastName(), s.studentID(), s.GPA());
      }
   }
}
class Student implements Comparable{
String firstName,lastName;
int studentID=0;
double GPA=0.0;
public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int studentID, double GPA) {      
  if(firstName==null||lastName==null||studentID==0||GPA==0.0){
      throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  }  
  this.firstName=firstName;
  this.lastName=lastName;
  this.studentID=studentID;
  this.GPA=GPA;
  }
  public String firstName(){
      return firstName;
  }
  public String lastName(){
      return lastName;
  }
  public int studentID(){
      return studentID;
  }
  public double GPA(){
      return GPA;
  }
  @Override
  public int compareTo(Object o){
    double f=GPA-((Student)o).GPA;//I am not able to understand how this line works please explain me especially this part"((Student).o).GPA". For what we are using this and how it works.
    if(f==0.0)
       return 0;
    else if(f<0.0)
       return -1;
    else
       return 1;        
   }
}
```

Comment: `Comparable` doesn't seem related to the actual error you're getting, but in any event, it should be implementing `Comparable<Student>`, not a raw `Comparable`, and it shouldn't have to do the cast at all in the first place.

Comment: I think you should accept my other answer because that is the reason your program was crashing. The one you accepted is only addressing your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax in your printf seems to be wrong.

Try doing this instead. Also I added a System.out.println() because all of the lines were being printed on the same line.

```
    for(Object obj:studentarray){
        s=(Student)obj;
        System.out.printf("NAME = %s %s STUDENT ID = %d GPA = %f", s.firstName(), s.lastName(), s.studentID(), s.GPA());
        System.out.println();
    }
```

As far as books go, I have heard nothing but good things about [Effective Java](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683)
The author of this book also wrote lots of the Collections library code.

Comment: Please let me know about my other doubts also if I want to implement this code

Comment: I will post a second answer in a moment, to correct your compiler warnings.

Answer (score 0):

As Louis said:

```
class Student implements Comparable<Student> {
    // more fun code
}
```

You need the type (Student) that this object may be compared to.

Good luck!

Comment: This has nothing to do with the issue at hand. OP's code is crashing from a different issue. It's not your fault though, the question needs to be edited.

Answer (score 0):

As requested, here is my second answer to help you with your compiler warnings. You need to specify a type parameter to `Comparable` and `TreeSet` because they are generic

New code:

```
import java.util.TreeSet;
public class ComparableTest
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        TreeSet<Student> studentset=new TreeSet<Student>();
        studentset.add(new Student("mike","hauffmann",101,4.0));
        studentset.add(new Student("john","lynn",102,2.8));
        studentset.add(new Student("jim","maxx",103,3.6));
        studentset.add(new Student("kelly","grant",104,2.3));
        Object studentarray[]=studentset.toArray();//this line needs explanation. Why are we creating an array of Object class? Is there any other alternative to this program without referring to Object class?
        Student s;
        for(Object obj:studentarray)
        {
            s=(Student)obj;
            System.out.printf("NAME = %s %s STUDENT ID = %d GPA = %f", s.firstName(), s.lastName(), s.studentID(), s.GPA());
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}



class Student implements Comparable<Student>
{
    String firstName,lastName;
    int studentID=0;
    double GPA=0.0;

    public Student(String firstName, String lastName, int studentID, double GPA) {      
        if(firstName==null||lastName==null||studentID==0||GPA==0.0){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }  
        this.firstName=firstName;
        this.lastName=lastName;
        this.studentID=studentID;
        this.GPA=GPA;
    }
    public String firstName(){
        return firstName;
    }
    public String lastName(){
        return lastName;
    }
    public int studentID(){
        return studentID;
    }
    public double GPA(){
        return GPA;
    }
    @Override
    public int compareTo(Student o){
        double f=GPA-((Student)o).GPA;//I am not able to understand how this line works please explain me especially this part"((Student).o).GPA". For what we are using this and how it works.
        if(f==0.0)
            return 0;
        else if(f<0.0)
            return -1;
        else
            return 1;        
    }

}
```